# To call a file where i create a class

Tags: wordpress, class, plugins

I have a directory structure.

```
-Main
  -admin
   -admin.php
  -user
 myfile.php
```

in the admin.php i have a class name "createPost". in that class i have written like bellow

```
<?php
// admin setting for wordpress

class wp_adminsettings {

  static $instance = false;


  private function __construct() {
    add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'wp_post_type' ) );
    .......................
    .......................
     hear i call all the add_action hook.
    .......................
    .......................
  }

    public static function getInstance() {
        if ( !self::$instance )
            self::$instance = new self;
        return self::$instance;
     }
```

then i create all the method like bellow given one...

```
  public function wp_post_type {
    $plugin_url = plugins_url();
    $labels = array(
    'name'               => _x( 'Badges', 'post type general name' ),
    'singular_name'      => _x( 'Badge', 'post type singular name' ),
    'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'book' ),
    'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Badge' ),
    'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Badge' ),
    'new_item'           => __( 'New Badge' ),
    'all_items'          => __( 'Badges' ),
    'view_item'          => __( 'View Badge' ),
    'search_items'       => __( 'Search Badges' ),
    'not_found'          => __( 'No badges found' ),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No badges found in the Trash' ), 
    'parent_item_colon'  => '',
    'menu_name'          => 'Badges',
    );
    $args = array(
    'labels'        => $labels,
    'description'   => 'Holds our badges and badge specific data',
    'public'        => true,
    'menu_position' => 5,
    'supports'      => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail' ),
    'menu_icon' => plugins_url( '/images/badge.png', __FILE__ ),
    'has_archive'   => true,
    );
    register_post_type( 'badge', $args );   
  }
```

Now all my code in the "admin.php" create a post type. i want to call the class in the  "myfile.php". because i want create a plugin for trail (to create custom post type). So how can i call the class in that "myfile.php". So that i create a custom post type.

Comment: `...i want to call the class in the "myfile.php"...` ¿What class, a class in "myfile.php", the "createPost" class or the "wp_adminsettings" class? It's a bit confusing. On the other hand, ¿what's the problem you are facing calling the class, whatever it is?

Comment: Already i gave the file structure previously. i have "myfile.php" in the main folder and i have create a class in admin.php . Now i want to call the class named "createpost" to the "myfile.php". what should i write in the myfile.php to call the class ,so that i create custom post type as i describe previously.